# Group markers for better view on the map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have created an function that shows all my photos on a Google Maps map trough markers. I'm very glad over the result but the thing is that a lot of the markers are on almost the same spot (see picture #1). I have tested the MarkerClustererPlus solution but it doesn't shows every markers when I have zoomed it to the max (see picture #2 and the position on the map is the same as on picture #1).

I want a function that shows a single marker if there is more than 10 markers close together (see picture #3). When I click on these grouped markers, a infowindow will appear and shows all the grouped photos that belongs to the grouped marker, if you know what I mean. How can I accomplish something like this?

Thanks in advance.

Picture #1
[image: a lot of markers on the same place]

Picture #2
[image: MarkerClustererPlus problem]

Picture #3
[image: better grouped markers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10674273/1314132 is close to what you are looking for 
I think. It covers:

- Sorting markers and identifying markers that occupy the same location.
- Merging markers at the same location into a single marker.
- Creating a single `InfoWindow` that displays separate data in a table for markers that share the same location.

I believe you would just have to change the logic that identifies markers at the same location to identify a specific set of markers that are close together and then modify the `InfoWindow` content to display your photos rather than the data shown in the current example. It seems like it would be fairly straightforward to make both of these changes.

### EDIT that updates the original answer to use Google Maps v3:

**Step 1:** Sort the marker data to allow identification of the markers that occupy the same location:

```
markerArray.sort( function( a, b ) {
    var aLat = a.Latitude, bLat = b.Latitude;               
    if ( aLat !== bLat ) { return aLat - bLat; }
    else { return a.Longitude - b.Longitude; }
});
```

**Step 2:** Add a new function that creates a "special" marker for colocated members of the `markerArray`:

```
var specialMarkers = null;

function createSpecialMarker( specialMarkers ) {
    var infoWinContent = "<table class='special-infowin-table'>";

    for ( var i = 0; i < specialMarkers.length; i++ ) {
        infoWinContent +=
            "<tr>" +
            "<td class='special-table-label'>" +
                "Visited Place [" + (i+1) + "]" +
            "</td>" + 
            "<td class='special-table-cell'>" +
                specialMarkers[i].nome + " on : " + specialMarkers[i].data +
            "</td></tr>";
    }
    infoWinContent += "</table>";

    var mrkrData = specialMarkers[0];
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng( mrkrData.Latitude, mrkrData.Longitude );
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker( point );
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        map.openInfoWindowHtml( point, infoWinContent );
    });

    return marker;
}
```

**Step 3:** Iterate over the marker data, identify groupings that have a location where *both* Latitude and Longitude are within a predefined `margin`, show them on the map using a special marker, and handle all of the marker data at other locations "normally":

```
var margin = 50;
for ( var i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++ ) {
    var current = markerArray[i];
    var coLocated = null;
    var j = 0, matchWasFound = false;

    if ( i < ( markerArray.length - 1 ) ) {
        do {
            var next = markerArray[ i + ++j ];
            if ( next !== undefined ) {    //just to be safe
                if ( ( ( next.Latitude - current.Latitude ) < margin ) &&
                       ( ( next.Longitude - current.Longitude ) < margin ) )
                {
                    matchWasFound = true;
                    if ( coLocated === null ) {
                        coLocated = new Array( current, next);
                    }
                    else { coLocated.push( next ); }
                }
                else { matchWasFound = false; }
            }
            else { matchWasFound = false; }
        }
        while ( matchWasFound )

        if ( coLocated != null ) {
           var coLoMarker = createSpecialMarker( coLocated );
            if ( specialMarkers === null ) {
                specialMarkers = new Array( coLoMarker );
            }
            else {
                specialMarkers.push( coLoMarker );
            }

            i += --j;
            continue;
        }

        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            markerArray[i].Latitude, markerArray[i].Longitude);
        description = "Visited place : " + markerArray[i].name +
                        " on : " + markerArray[i].data;
         //Simply creates a regular marker:
        createMarker( point, i + 1, description );
    }
}
```

The idea is to produce a single marker and let the InfoWindow convey the multiple pieces of information about the location that are important, ending up with something that looks like this:

[image]

I haven't run this actual code, but it is based on code that runs every day. This is more intended to give you a fairly detailed look at the approach and share a body of code that should get you pretty darn close to a usable solution, with the understanding that it may need a little tweaking and debugging.

Comment: Sweet! I'll try your function as soon as possible :D

Comment: One problem though - the `gl_list` is not defined. How can I fix this? Worth says that I'm using Google Maps JavaScript v3.

Comment: The `gl_list` is something that I copied from the original question, just to give the answer context into the code example the poster gave. It is a JavaScript `Array` that contains all of the markers. I just remembered that some of the answer was coded for the Google Maps **v2** API, so I have updated the code to use v3 and added it to my original answer above.

Comment: Many thanks for your edit, but I can't get it work! I'm getting this error message all the time: `Uncaught ReferenceError: markerArray is not defined (anonymous function)`. Here is how I have it now: http://jsfiddle.net/EQX8y/

Comment: Well, I can't code that part. I have put references to `markerArray` in the code sample, to show you how you may use the JavaScript `Array` of markers. But you have to create the `markerArray` so that it is in scope for the functions I have shown. You must also have the data for the markers and use that to call the functions I have provided. So I guess there is a **Step 0** that you must perform: create the `markerArray` and load it with your marker data. Does that make sense?

Comment: Many thanks yet again! I have mark your answer as correct :) Yes. It makes sense that you said :)

Comment: I got it working now but the markers are not grouping as on your example picture. Please see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/vwyYG/. I have added 3 markers which 2 of them has the same coordinates. I want to group every markers that are within 50 meters radius. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I have adjusted the logic in **Step 3** to better match your situation as follows: I have added a `var margin` that sets a linear proximity threshold value. I have adjusted the logic so that it no longer requires the exact same location; it now checks to find markers that are both located within the margin in latitude and within the margin in longitude. This is not exactly a distance check, but it should work well. You may also adjust the `margin` to tweak the behavior. If you must have exact distance comparison, just let me know and I will be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I'm getting `createMarker is not defined` after I have added `var margin = 50;` and the new if-code with margin. Please see the updated example on my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/vwyYG/

Comment: The `createMarker` function isn't implemented in the code I provided in my answer. My assumption was that you already had an existing function to create your markers in your existing code. You just need to use your existing function and rename it to `createMarker' or change the code I provided so that it calls your existing function. Or you could take your existing code that creates your markers and add your own `createMarker` function. You have to have that existing code, because your original question showed that you were creating markers. If not, just let me know - glad to help.

Comment: Ah! Now I know more :) Thanks! But I'm only adding the markers through the last for loop in my code on jsFiddle. I don't use any function of that kind to add the markers :) How shall I do to make this work perfectly?

Comment: All you should have to do is move the code inside your for loop (not the for loop itself, because that is already in the code I provided) into a function named `createMarker` and change the signature of `createMarker` to fit what you need. I would expect you probably just need to pass a `google.maps.LatLng` and any content you want to include in an `InfoWindow`.

Comment: Okej. So `point` and `description` in your `createMarker` is kind of "hitpoints" for a function? For example `function createMarker(point, description) { ... }`?

Comment: Right. You can pass in a `google.maps.LatLng` as the `point` and then the `description` parameter is a placeholder for whatever content you want to place in an `InfoWindow` for that marker. Of course, you are free to adjust it as makes sense, but those are the general data elements that are used elsewhere in the code, so it's just a placeholder.

Comment: Many thanks! But the markers does not appear on the map after I done what you have told me to do :/ What have I missed? Please see the updated code here: http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/vwyYG/

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look at your jsFiddle, because I'm fighting to make a deadline by Monday. But I haven't forgotten you; I promise I will take a look at the code as soon as I have the time.

Comment: Your first problem is that the `locations` array you are creating is simply creating a 2-dimensional array. You need the elements of the array to be JavaScript objects that contain properties with the correct names. The code I gave you is meant to retrieve data from the elements in the array using property names, such as: `loc.Latitude`, `loc.Longitude`, `loc.data`, etc. You need to change the creation of the locations.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not good at JavaScript at all so I don't know exactly how I shall accomplish that you said :/ :)

Comment: I think we have pretty much overloaded this question, with way more than normal comments. At this point, I think we should end the conversation on this question. I suggest that you open a new question that asks about how to declare an inline array of JavaScript objects. I will be happy to answer, as will others I'm sure, but I think this question is getting overloaded.